# Combining react-i18next with zod and a backend

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, zod

We are using react-i18next and i18next-http-backend to load our translations from an api endpoint.

We've now added Zod as our validation library and are looking to translate the error messages to Dutch as well. I've added zod-i18n-map, i18next-resources-to-backend and i18next-chained-backend to the mix to chain our existing backend with the resources provided by zod-i18n-map.

Our i18n.js file in our project now looks like this:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-chained-backend';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import {z} from 'zod';
import {zodI18nMap} from 'zod-i18n-map';
import translation from 'zod-i18n-map/locales/nl/zod.json';

i18n.use(initReactI18next)
    .use(Backend)
    .init({
        lng: 'nl',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        backend: {
            backends: [
                HttpApi,
                resourcesToBackend({
                    nl: {zod: translation},
                }),
            ],
            backendOptions: [
                {
                    loadPath: process.env.API_URL + '/translations/{{lng}}',
                },
            ],
        },
    });

z.setErrorMap(zodI18nMap);

export default i18n;
```

Our previous translations, loaded from the Http backend, still work but zod doesn't seem to want to play ball. Form is still outputting "Required", "String must contain ..." and other English errors, while the language is set to Dutch.

I have a feeling `z.setErrorMap(zodI18nMap);` isn't correctly working because I'd expect to see a concatenated string of some sort (seeing as the zod.json file is sorted by keys). But the resources aren't properly loading either because if I try to manually translate `{t('zod.errors.invalid_type_received_undefined')}` I simply get the untranslated string back as well...

Comment: did you manage to fix this am facing a close error

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is facing the same issue as Combining react-i18next with zod and a backend maybe the following would help

**partialBundledLanguages: true,**

```
i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(
    resourcesToBackend(
      (language: string, namespace: string) =>
        import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`),
    ),
  )
i18next.init({
  partialBundledLanguages: true,
  resources: {
    en: {
      zod: enTranslation,
    },
    ar: {
      zod: arTranslation,
    },
  },
});
```

as per documentation of i18next for partialBundledLanguages

> If you want to lazy load some translations via a backend plugin, you
> may need to use the partialBundledLanguages: true option. This allows
> some resources (or no resources) to be set on initialization while
> others can be loaded using a backend connector.

Comment: This helped me setup backend and zod togheter. Thx